# New session for every domain name

Tags: php, session, nginx

I'm running Ubuntu / nginx and php-fpm. When I open my website http://www.mydomain.com I have to log in and a session is being created by PHP. When I log on to http://mydomain.com I have to log in again and another session is being created.

How can I prevent PHP from creating new sessions and stick with one? Or is this rather a web server issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your sessions are based on cookies, and cookies are domain specific. `www.domain.com` is technically a subdomain of `domain.com`, although it is rarely treated as such, and the browser will act as if it were a completely different server. You can work around the problem by passing the session id as a GET (or POST) parameter as appropriate.

See [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) or the PHP manual for an explanation of how to do it. All you really need to do is include the constant `SID` in all your links etc - this is defined when you call `session_start()` and is a string in the format of a URL parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params) and set the domain to `.mydomain.com`. Also [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params) needs to be called before each [session_start](http://php.net/session_start)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the cookie domain to make sure the cookie is seen valid for both www and non-www http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: Only problem with this is that you are relying on te client to respect that instruction, but yeh, this is a simpler solution as you don't have modify your code in any other way...